# With git, how does one revert text changes to a file without reverting the move?

Tags: git

I have a commit where I both moved the file and changed the text content. Using `git log --stat -M` I see this change:

```
.../{packages/components/src => src/components}/Card/styles.css | 36 +-
```

I'd like to revert or amend the commit to only include the move changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate moving and then committing the content change, this is what you can do:

```
git branch temp # set a temp branch where we are right now
# get the original content into the final location
git show HEAD~1:blah/packages/components/src/Card/styles.css > blah/src/components/Card/styles.css
# create a new revision (amended comment)
git commit --amend -m moving file"
# get the final comment
git checkout temp -- blah/src/components/Card/styles.css
git commit -m "Changed content"
```

And you are done. Now you can delete temp branch if everything looks good

```
git branch -D temp
```